# How can I install Meteor-Up (mup) correctly?

Tags: meteor, installation, npm, ubuntu-14.04, meteor-up

I am trying to install Meteor-Up (mup) for deploying an app from my Ubuntu 14.04 laptop to a Ubuntu 14.04 server, but it does not seem to install correctly. How can I install mup correctly?

I know that I need npm to in order to install mup. So, I have successfully installed npm with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install npm
```

Then, I try to install mup with:

```
$ sudo npm install -g mup
```

Install log:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mup
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mup
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemiral
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cjson
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.7.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uuid
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nodemiral
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cjson
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore/1.7.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonlint/1.6.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/handlebars
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/debug
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/jsonlint/1.6.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nomnom
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/JSV
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nomnom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/JSV
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/uglify-js
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/chalk
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/underscore
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/strip-ansi
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/source-map
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ansi-styles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/has-color
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/amdefine
/usr/local/bin/mup -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup/bin/mup
mup@0.7.7 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mup
├── rimraf@2.2.8
├── colors@0.6.2
├── underscore@1.7.0
├── uuid@1.4.2
├── cjson@0.3.0 (jsonlint@1.6.0)
└── nodemiral@0.3.11 (debug@0.7.4, ejs@0.8.8, handlebars@1.0.12)
```

After this whenever I try to use the `$ mup command` or `$ mup -help` (to check that it installed properly), I get the following message:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

Am I missing part of the installation process, since it seems to recognize that mup is a command? I would like to know how to fix this issue and an explanation of the problem would be a bonus. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Node.js was not installed properly, double check to see if you have installed node properly following this instructions.

[Linux](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/)
[Other Operating Systems](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)

Node is not properly linked, using this command should fix that. But a better solution is to reinstall Node.js from those links.

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
```

Now it recognizes the commands `$ mup` and `$ mup -help`.

Comment: @Chetan what operating system are you using?

Answer (score 3):

I think you need to install nodejs via this: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/installing-node.js-via-package-manager#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions

That'll fix the node issue.